# Allow null values for foreign key ASP.NET Core MVC Code First Approach with EFW?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc

I am designing a `Model` in my `ASP.NET Core MVC` where I need to refer to the `EmployeeId` field from `ApplicationUser` table in my `Model`. This `field` will be called `UserId`. However, I have another field in the same `Model`  that I am designing, I have another `field` called `OtherUser` (which is nullable), which will store the name of a `Guest User`. So, when I have to enter the `Guest User's` name, I will have to put `null` in the `UserId` field of my `Model`.

```
    // In ApplicationUser Table
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Employee Id")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

And, the `OtherUser` field in the `Model` that I am designing is in the following way:

```
    public string OtherUser { get; set; }
```

I looked up online for probable solution. Most of them were prompting me to put `?` at the `datatype` that would make the field `nullable`. One solution that I tried was:

```
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

However, I was getting the following `Error` on writing like this: `The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'.`

Comment: `string` is already nullable, don't need `?`

Comment: But, since it is a `Foreign Key` field referencing the `UserId` field from the `ApplicationUser` table (which is a `required` field in that table), won't it cause issues if I don't enter any value/leave the field blank?

Comment: Why would it? It's not a required field.

Comment: Yes. I was also thinking the same. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Only non-nullable types are made NOT NULL at the database level by default. A string, whether a foreign key or not, will be nullable unless you add the `Required` attribute. Here you obviously *wouldn't* want that, but in other cases where you want something like a string foreign key to be NOT NULL, remember to add `Required`.